# How to auto-approve internal pingbacks?

Tags: comments, links, moderation, disqus, pingbacks

Whenever I write a post on my blog and link to a previous post, that pingback shows up as a comment needing to be approved.

I am running [Disqus](http://disqus.com), but this was happening even pre-use of that plugin.

[image: comment settings]

What is the fix for this behavior?

Comment: These are a special kind of comments, called ["Pingbacks"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks) (or "Trackbacks", the older term). Disqus [seemed to have issues with them](http://blog.fublo.net/2010/08/pingbacks-trackbacks-disqus-wordpress/). Do you see them in the Disqus moderation queue or only in the WordPress moderation queue?

Comment: @Jan Fabry, this behavior presented itself even prior to using Disqus - and it's in the WP moderation queue

Comment: @Jan actually pingbacks and trackbacks are quite different technologically and aren't different terms for same thing, link you provided covers that quite well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment handling is somewhat difficult to follow in code. My educated guess is that you have comment whitelist enabled (*Comment author must have previously approved comment*), but since pingbacks are not identifiable by author they are treated as requiring moderation.

Answer (score 0):

you may use this plugin :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disabler/

i found this function somewhere on the internet (but can't remember where...). it may do what you are looking for :

```
// Remove self pings
add_action( 'pre_ping', 'my_no_self_ping' );
function my_no_self_ping( &$links ) {
    $home = get_option( 'home' );
    foreach ( $links as $l => $link )
        if ( 0 === strpos( $link, $home ) )
            unset( $links[$l] );
}
```

Comment: Trackbacking yourself is a waste of resources.

Comment: @Dan Gayle - when it provides forward backlinking, it is distinctly not a "waste of resources"

Comment: This is the exact opposite of the question.