# Why does WordPress cap the number of pingbacks it attempts per post?

Tags: pingbacks

When using the pingback feature of WordPress, why does it cap the number of attempted pingbacks?

For example, if you [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18668/5173) to multiple other posts on your own blog, it will only do one or two pingbacks per publish operation (ie when you 'publish' (and/or it goes live, if it's scheduled), or when you edit and save a published post).

It would *seem* that processing *all* pingbacks/trackbacks would be better behavior. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: citation needed  ;) Why do you think there is a cap, where do you see it in code or documentation?

Comment: @MarkKaplun - I can prove the cap by writing a blog post, and linking to more than one or two previous posts on the same site: put in five back links, and only one or two will be processed per publish attempt.

Comment: that just proves that things are not done "immediately", or that you have something that blocking the pingbacks.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - nothing is blocking them, as the first couple work fine. And when you do a save/republish on an existing post, the next link or two is processed. Feel free to replicate this behavior yourself.

Comment: again, that just means that you might be impatient and nothing more.

Comment: at least I can not imagine any need for such cap.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - it's not "impatient" when it never happens. Without manual intervention (ie, editing and republishing the post), later links after the first couple are never processed. True for posts a few minutes old. And true for ones a few years old.

Answer (score 0):

The situation for Wordpress 5.1:

1. After publishing a post, `wp-includes/post.php`'s `_publish_post_hook()` schedules the `do_pings` action for immediate execution. This is put into the "cron" option in database.
2. Whenever the cron job runs, `do_all_pings()` is executed, which sends pingbacks for all outstanding posts.
3. `pingback()` extracts all links from the post text and sends a pingback to each of them.

There is no limitation to 2 links anywhere.